# in hook_preprocess_node, how to tell if node is being edited?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

In hook_preprocess_node (or other themable hook), what is the easiest way to tell if node is being edited? I would like to add some javascript only when viewing the node, not editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hook_preprocess_node()` doesn't get fired for node edit pages so you don't need to do any checks, you can just add your JS as normal.